# Wrap a span around pagination text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure I can't edit, because of our CMS and as you can see it's missing a class/span making it difficult to style the active page, which is the '5'. Meanwhile, the end chevron is removed when the last pagination is active, which is the '7'.

Can someone provide a jquery solution to wrap `<span></span>` around the '5' when its active and when the last pagination is active, which is the '7', so I may style it?

1. The active page will increase/decrease depending on the number selected, so it's not always going to be '5' and a '7' that requires the span.
2. The jquery shouldn't touch summary "xx records / xx records per page / x pages" that exists within the same div block.
3. When the last pagination is clicked, which is the 7, the chevron is removed and the active number is next to the summary. This isolated pagination would need the span tag without affecting the summary.

This is my fiddle to provide a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/yay9W/

Example 1:

```
<div class="pag">
    <a class="prev" href="http://www.example.com">‹‹</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">3</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">4</a>
    5
    <a href="http://www.example.com">6</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">7</a>
    <a class="prev" href="http://www.example.com">››</a>
    xx records / xx records per page / x pages 
</div>
```

Example 2: Then should the last pagination be active, in this case its the 7, the html looks like this:

```
<div class="pag">
    <a class="prev" href="http://www.example.com">‹‹</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">3</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">4</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">5</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">6</a>
    7 xx records / xx records per page / x pages 
</div>
```

This is my fiddle to provide a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/bqyYA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we want to wrap any content that is a text node except for the last one (which holds your summary), this should work:

```
$('div.pag').contents(':not(:last-child)').filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})
.wrap('<span></span>')
```

The .contents function is similar to the .children function, except that it also returns text nodes.  The filter checks for a text node type.  An added filter skips the final child node.

Here's the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/36Wwt/

Comment: I wasn't anticipating this, but it seems when the last pagination is clicked it last-child pseudo class does not apply. I updated my description above with my example. Would you have an enhancement to this exception?

Comment: That complicates things a bit, because suddenly your page number and your summary text are in the same text node... which means you've got to somehow parse and split that and stick in another DOM node.  I played with it a bit but unfortunately don't have a good answer for you at this point.

Answer (score 2):

This should run for most of the cases .

The above solution does not work in many cases such as the markup in the fiddle that i have pasted here

```
var elms = $('.pag').contents().filter(function () {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != '';
});

elms.each(function () {
  var num = Number(this.nodeValue);
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    this.nodeValue = num;
    $(this).wrap('<span class="lonerPage"></span>');
  }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yay9W/1/)**

Comment: I updated my description with a behavior I wasn't expecting when the last pagination is clicked. I created my html to show you what I mean. 
http://jsfiddle.net/evanmoore/s3WWb/1/

Comment: The problem is in the second `div.pag` .. Where in `7  xx records / xx records per page / x pages</div>`  comes on the same line.. This makes the parser treat the whole sentence as a single text node instead of multiple nodes